# Get UILabel.text at indexPath.row in collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to get the text whatever CollectionViewCell is selected by a user. This is my currently cell structure.

```
class CategoryCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var categoryImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryType: UILabel!
}
```

I want to pass over this information to the next view controller - how can I get the UILabel.text at the selectedCell and pass it to the next view controller?

Comment: Let me make sure I understand your question before I begin to answer. So you have a label with some text that you want to pass to another controller?

Comment: Yes, I need to get the UILabels text at the selected UICollectionViewCell then pass that text and pass it to the next view controller!

Comment: Okay give me a few minutes.

Comment: Now how are you going to the other view? Via selection of the cell?

Comment: One a cell is selected, it triggers a segue to the next controller (a push segue)

Answer (score 4):

I will specify a way based on an assumption. If a cell is having UILabel there has to be an input for that label to add text either in cellForItemAtIndexPath or sending value to cell to add it in UILabel.

This Answer it totally based on that assumption. If you are giving a specific data to label based on indexpath then when a cell is selected get the indexPath and fetch the data from the datasource.

The other way is in didSelectItemAtIndexPath function

```
  let cell:CategoryCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
  let labelText = cell.categoryType.text
```

Comment: Yes you could get the cell's label's text this way also but you still need to pass it to the second viewcontroller via the prepareForSegue() method.

Answer (score 3):

So to pass data between view controllers you can use the prepareForSegue method.

**Inside viewcontroller one:**

In the prepareForSegue method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if(segue.identifier == "yourID")
{
    let cell = sender as! UICollectionViewCell // this should be your custom cell class
    var myIndex = viewCollect.indexPathForCell(cell) // this is how you get the index if you need it

    let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2
    destination.dateString = cell.myLabel.text // where dateString is a String variable in viewcontroller 2
 }
}
```

- So we create a cell from the sender object
- Get access to the cell's label
- Create the destination to the ViewController2
- Then assign the label's text to a variable in ViewController2

**This has worked for me in the past. If it doesn't work let me know.**